# Check if a dll is installed and available

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to make an application that may rely on a Wacom tablet. It is not necessary for the program to work, but it is a nice addition. Although, it should also work on computers without the Wintab32.dll installed and I would like to make a check to see if the DLL is available.

This piece of code generates an error and I would like to catch the error before it is generated. I am using WintabDN to support .net Wacom applications.

```
if (WintabDN.CWintabInfo.IsWintabAvailable())
{
    // Initialize Wintab
    WintabLib.Initialize(true);
    WintabLib.OnWintabPacketReceived += WintabLib_OnWintabPacketReceived;
}
```

> FAILED IsWintabAvailable: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load
>   DLL 'Wintab32.dll': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>       at WintabDN.CWintabFuncs.WTInfoA(UInt32 wCategory_I, UInt32 nIndex_I, IntPtr IpOutput_O)
>       at WintabDN.CWintabInfo.IsWintabAvailable()

The problem with this error is that it is a messagebox and not an exception thrown by the package. How can I prevent this messagebox from showing up?

Comment: Why not just use File.Exists() method?

Comment: In what folder should I look for this DLL then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because the underlying exception is already being handled.

Trying to block the messagebox from showing is going to be difficult, if not impossible.  You *can* do something really hacky like a watcher thread to catch the foreground window changing, then manually sending a mouse click message to the application's underlying message queue to try and trigger the OK button on the message box.

So I have two suggestions: [this is the official topic on DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx); you can use it to emulate the search and find the file in advance.

If you don't want to do that you could import the `LoadLibrary` method from `kernel32.dll` and then call that to try and load the DLL that the WintabDN library is trying to use; if you get an exception then you know that the WintabDN library will also.  Here's an *almost* related topic that'll help bind LoadLibrary: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try following which answers:

(The Wintab SDK examples won't run without Wintab installed on the system. How can I make my program work if there is no tablet (no Wintab) on the system?)

http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/docs/WacomWindevFAQ.html

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this messagebox from showing up?

You can't:

```
    public static bool IsWintabAvailable()
    {
        IntPtr buf = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool status = false;

        try
        {
            status = (CWintabFuncs.WTInfoA(0, 0, buf) > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAILED IsWintabAvailable: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        return status;
    }
```

:D

I hate library developers, writing such kind of code. They shouldn't decide, what error-handling mechanism you will choose.

But it is open-source, you can fix this issue.
Or you can post a bug at their tracker and wait, when they will fix it.